# InDesign best practice for headings in separate columns

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, page-layout, editorial-design

I'm wondering if there is a better way to set up this type of layout where the headings are in the left column, and the body copy is in the right column. Currently I am using a separate text box for the headings, but as the text reflows, there is a lot of manual re-adjusting to the position of the text boxes.

[image]

I tried using First Line Indent and keeping everything in one box, but then headings get messed up when they extend to the next line.

Any editorial pros out there want to share some tips?

Comment: "then headings get messed up when they extend to the next line." Do you mean when your headings require more than one line? I'm thinking anchored objects might be useful here...

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in a comment, this could be achieved using *Anchored Objects*. I've written an answer about that [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/133832/84899). But if your design is as simple as you show on your screenshot, it can actually be achieved only using paragraph styles in one single text frame.

*Edit: I've realized that this method only works in a single text frame. If the text flows to another text frame, the body copy ends up in the left column. I will look into fixing this if possible.*

---

Make one single text frame that has the width of all columns (your grid shows 6 columns, but you only seem to use 3). Select the text frame, right-click it and enter *Text Frame Options*. Under the *General* tab, set the *Number* of columns to *3* and the *Gutter* to whatever you want.

[image]

Your text must be in one continuous story. You'll need 4 paragraph styles to achieve this layout:

[image]

The **Heading** style has no special settings. It's important though that *Span Columns > Paragraph Layout* is set to the default "Single Column":

[image]

The **Body** style is for the main body text. It must have *Span Columns > Paragraph Layout* set to *Span Columns* and *Span* set to *2* columns:

[image]

The **First** style is for the first paragraph of body text. It must be *Based On* the **Body** style and have one additional setting. *Keep Options > Start Paragraph* must be set to *In Next Column*:

[image]

Finally we need the **Breaker** style to end an article. This might annoy some people, as we need to have an empty line. It can also be *Based On* the **Body** style with one additional setting. It must have *Span Columns > Paragraph Layout* set to *Span Columns* and *Span* set to *All* columns:

[image]

This style can be used to control the space between articles. If you want no space, you can set the *Leading* to *0*.

Comment: Clever! Very clever indeed. Sort of gridbox placement meets InDesign.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, thanks! That *Breaker* style annoys me a little, but I don't think it can be avoided.

Comment: Actually, couldn’t you avoid it by setting the Heading style to start in next column as well? Or would that move the heading to the second column and wreaking complete havoc?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I'm afraid it's the latter. 

Comment: A bit hacky, but you can set the Body style to span all columns with a left indent equivalent to the first column + gutter (also making sure that the First style isn’t based on the Body style). That would achieve it, though of course you’d have to update the style if the frame/column changes its width… (Also, don’t have headings longer than the first paragraph with this hack, or there’ll be gaps.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, actually I think I have to do something like that anyway. Just realized that when the story flows to another frame I think it will start in the left column. But I can't test it now. Going to bed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your setup or how many of these pages you've got, **a table setup** could be easier to keep under control and that can also spread across multiple pages.

Just need two columns, drop everything left and right, and then customize the formatting & spacing of all cells in one go, apply styles in one go, etc.