# Adobe InDesign: How can I change the location of the footnotes?

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, footnotes

I need to change the location of the footnotes. Instead of the footnotes being at the bottom of the page, they should be in the side column of the main text. I also need it to be exactly on the corresponding line where the footnote is written and appears in the main text (as shown in the image).

It would be interesting if I could automate this process. I will be working periodically with articles and would like it to work this way.
Do you know how to do this? Is there a script?

[image]

Comment: I think this requires some manual work or a very specific script. I don't think you can use ordinary footnotes for this. This question is related and might give you some inspiration: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/133825

Answer (score 2):

In InDesign footnotes can only be positioned in the bottom of the text frame where the footnote marker is placed. The only way to make sidenotes positioned next to their marker is by using [Anchored Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/anchored-objects.html).

Setting it up manually is cumbersome. Especially the numbering is hard to keep consistent. Scripting seems to be the best option.

I googled ["indesign sidenotes script"](https://www.google.com/search?q=indesign+sidenotes+script) and the first hit seems to be what you are looking for.

Peter Kahrel made a whole suite of scripts called [**Dynamic Sidenotes**](https://creativepro.com/files/kahrel/indesign/sidenotes.html).

There are separate scripts for:

- Converting existing footnotes to sidenotes.
- Adding new sidenotes.
- Changing the width of all sidenotes.
- Stacking sidenotes (in case they overlap).
- Restarting numbering according to page, spread or section.
- Resetting sidenotes to their initial position.
- Reverting sidenotes back to footnotes.

I made a quick test in InDesign 2021 and they seem to work as intended.